# Realm Error Encrypted interprocess sharing is currently unsupported

Tags: android, realm

Crashlytics showing error:

> Encrypted interprocess sharing is currently unsupported.SharedGroup has been opened by pid: 15277. Current pid is 23384. in io_realm_internal_SharedGroup.cpp line 113.

But, unable to reproduce the error. Done google search but not found any satisfactory answer

Comment: actually you are creating the Realm object in a thread and using it in another one so this is not supported for now... create a new Realm instance and use it

Comment: It says you have an encrypted Realm, and you are trying to access it from multiple processes.

Comment: See the information here https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1477#issuecomment-235147984 . I think it is only happened once after user updates the apk, right?

Comment: Actually i am unable to reproduce this issue. I found this on crashlytics

Comment: General cleanup, allowing the error and request to be read more efficiently.

Comment: When  we make the call on same file more than once on encrypted Ream then i am getting this issue

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue on simulator and I solved this by copying the realm files from Device directory to Home directory.